# reshape2: dcast when there are multiple values for one cell but keep this values

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape2

I have a data frame like that:

```
    HLA_Status    variable      value
1     PP            CCL24       9.645
2     PP            CCL24       56.32
3     PP            CCL24       7.268
4     PC            CCL24       5.698
5     PC            CCL24       89.457
6     PC            CCL24       78.23
7     PP            SPP1        23.12
8     PP            SPP1        36.32
9     PP            SPP1        17.268
10    PC            SPP1        2.698
11    PC            SPP1        9.457
12    PC            SPP1        8.23
```

I want to reshape my data frame with reshape2::dcast() and get this:

```
   HLA_Status        CCL24        SPP1
1      PP            9.645       23.12
2      PP            56.32       36.32
3      PP            7.268       17.268
13     PC            5.698       2.698
14     PC            89.457      9.457
15     PC            78.230      8.23
```

But I didn't manage to do this.

I tried this:

```
dcast(mydt, HLA_Status ~ variable, value.var = "value")
```

But it didn't work.

And I see on the documentation of reshape2 that if we have multiple values per cell we need to tell dcast how to aggregate the data.

I think my problem is to don't know what to give to fun.aggregate.

How can I get the wanted data frame by using reshape2 or others packages?

Comment: try this: `library(tidyr); mydt %>% spread(variable, value)`

Comment: When you provide a unique identifier to every row of your original dataframe (e.g. row number) it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with `dcast` (here from `data.table`) though you need a row identifier.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(dt, HLA_Status + rowid(HLA_Status, variable) ~ variable)
#   HLA_Status HLA_Status_1  CCL24   SPP1
#1:         PC            1  5.698  2.698
#2:         PC            2 89.457  9.457
#3:         PC            3 78.230  8.230
#4:         PP            1  9.645 23.120
#5:         PP            2 56.320 36.320
#6:         PP            3  7.268 17.268
```

**data**

```
dt <- fread("    HLA_Status    variable      value
     PP            CCL24       9.645
     PP            CCL24       56.32
     PP            CCL24       7.268
     PC            CCL24       5.698
     PC            CCL24       89.457
     PC            CCL24       78.23
     PP            SPP1        23.12
     PP            SPP1        36.32
     PP            SPP1        17.268
     PC            SPP1        2.698
     PC            SPP1        9.457
     PC            SPP1        8.23")
```

Comment: Great, I didn't know `rowid` before! With `reshape2` we could use `ave`, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `spread` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(HLA_Status, variable) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  spread(variable, value) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-row)

# A tibble: 6 x 3
#  HLA_Status CCL24  SPP1
#  <fct>     <dbl> <dbl>
#1   PC       5.70  2.70
#2   PC       89.5  9.46
#3   PC       78.2  8.23
#4   PP       9.64  23.1 
#5   PP       56.3  36.3 
#6   PP       7.27  17.3
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(HLA_Status = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("PC", "PP"), class = "factor"), 
variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("CCL24", "SPP1"), class = "factor"), 
value = c(9.645, 56.32, 7.268, 5.698, 89.457, 78.23, 23.12, 
36.32, 17.268, 2.698, 9.457, 8.23)), class = "data.frame", row.names = 
c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: Ok it works. May be add df=as.data.frame(df) to be precise?

Comment: @AdamBellaïche isn't it already a dataframe ?

Comment: function class() give me: [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"   "data.frame"

Comment: it should still work irrespective of that I believe.

Comment: Sorry? I don't understand

Comment: does the above solution work if you don't do `df = as.data.frame(df)` ?

Comment: Yes it works without df=as.data.frame(df) ! Your answer is very good.

Answer (score 1):

If `reshape2::dcast` is actually needed, there's a solution with `ave` (to get the identifiers, see *@markus*' answer):

```
reshape2::dcast(d, HLA_Status + ave(rep(1, nrow(d)), d[1:2], FUN=seq) ~ variable)
#   HLA_Status ave(rep(1, nrow(d)), d[1:2], FUN = seq)  CCL24   SPP1
# 1         PC                                       1  5.698  2.698
# 2         PC                                       2 89.457  9.457
# 3         PC                                       3 78.230  8.230
# 4         PP                                       1  9.645 23.120
# 5         PP                                       2 56.320 36.320
# 6         PP                                       3  7.268 17.268
```

***Data***

```
d <- structure(list(HLA_Status = c("PP", "PP", "PP", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
"PP", "PP", "PP", "PC", "PC", "PC"), variable = c("CCL24", "CCL24", 
"CCL24", "CCL24", "CCL24", "CCL24", "SPP1", "SPP1", "SPP1", "SPP1", 
"SPP1", "SPP1"), value = c(9.645, 56.32, 7.268, 5.698, 89.457, 
78.23, 23.12, 36.32, 17.268, 2.698, 9.457, 8.23)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend to switch to `tidyr` instead of using `reshape2`. However, if you really would like to use `dcast` this is the way to go

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
df <- structure(list(HLA_Status = c("PP", "PP", "PP", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
"PP", "PP", "PP", "PC", "PC", "PC"), variable = c("CCL24", "CCL24", 
"CCL24", "CCL24", "CCL24", "CCL24", "SPP1", "SPP1", "SPP1", "SPP1", 
"SPP1", "SPP1"), value = c(9.645, 56.32, 7.268, 5.698, 89.457, 
78.23, 23.12, 36.32, 17.268, 2.698, 9.457, 8.23)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = "data.frame")


df %>% 
  group_by(variable, HLA_Status) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  dcast(HLA_Status+id ~ variable, value.var = "value") %>%
  select(-id)

  HLA_Status  CCL24   SPP1
1         PC  5.698  2.698
2         PC 89.457  9.457
3         PC 78.230  8.230
4         PP  9.645 23.120
5         PP 56.320 36.320
6         PP  7.268 17.268
```

Comment: I don't care about which package is used. I see it is a little complicated with reshape2. But thank you